# {p:1} と {p:{value:1}}の違い。 {p:{value:1}}の形式名称は？

Tags: javascript

**何れもオブジェクトだと思うのですが、`{p:{value:1}}`は何と呼ぶのでしょうか？**
・値がオブジェクトで構成されている「キーと値のオブジェクト」？
・ネストしたオブジェクト？
・二次元オブジェクト？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ・値がオブジェクトで構成されている「キーと値のオブジェクト」？ 
>   ・ネストしたオブジェクト？

どちらも正解かと思います。

> ・二次元オブジェクト？

こちらはちょっと違うかと思います。
オブジェクト(連想配列)には二次元という考え方はありませんが強いて書くと

```
[{hoge:1,fuga:10},
{hoge:2,fuga:20},
{hoge:3,fuga:30},
{hoge:4,fuga:40}]
```

こんな感じでしょうか。(「オブジェクトの配列」「連想配列の配列」の方が正しいですが。)